# How to access an element on array obj

Tags: vue.js

I want to add an a href link `<a href=" ">Go Back</a>`

I want to bind the value from rows, which is an array:

```
rows: [["href": "href.com", "id"=>"10"], ["href":"href.com", "id"=>"20"]]
```

href value its the same on each array, so how can I get href without doing `v-for="row in rows"`

Comment: The array is not a valid javascript object. Do you mean `[{"href": "href.com", "id":"10"}, {"href":"href.com", "id":"20"}]`? In which case, you can simply do `rows[0]['href']`.

Comment: @Psidom my bad, that works please post the answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your array as `[{"href": "href.com", "id":"10"}, {"href":"href.com", "id":"20"}]` and all subarrays have the same `href`, you can extract the first element in the `rows` with `rows[0]` and then access the `href` key as a normal javascript object. In the template, you can write `<a :href="rows[0]['href']">Go Back</a>`.

Answer (score 2):

You currently have an array within an array. I assume your intention was to have an object within an array, like this:

`rows: [{"href": "href.com", "id": "10"}, {"href":"href.com", "id": "20"}]`

In which case you can do what [Psidom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4983450/psidom) suggested and access the object within the `rows` array with `rows[0]['href']` or do a v-for within `rows` like this:

```
<template v-for="row in rows" :key="row.id">
  <a :href="row.href">Link</a>
</template>
```

Comment: invalid proper declaration: `=>` fix this, everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't pay attention to what was inside each object. Fix'd.